# "'frmExport' not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level" in VB 2019

Tags: vb.net

I just added a new form to a VB 2019 project. It's a project that I first created in VB 2010. It adds the form OK, but it gives me a BC30451 error when I run a showdialog command on it. The new form has only 2 buttons on it with no code. Any help?

Here's all the code in the new form:

```
Public Class frmExport

    Public Sub frmExport_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Hide()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Code from the calling form:

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

    ' Data Export

    Timer1.Stop()
    Me.TopMost = False
    frmExport.ShowDialog()
    Me.TopMost = True
    Timer1.Start()

End Sub
```

Comment: In the form that has Button5, do you have an instance of frmExport declared somewhere?

Comment: Looks like you're using the default instance of the form, and not creating your own instance. `Dim fExport as New frmExport. fExport.ShowDialog()` etc.

Comment: I tried "Dim fExport as new frmExport." I got an error, "Type frmExport not defined."

Comment: It looks like it just does not recognize the new form I added to the project.